# How to get returned object on http 422 response on AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetwoking v 2.2.4 as a networking library on iOS. It assumes non http 2xx (http 200 as success ) response as error and throws on error block like this:

```
NSError *error= nil;
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:user options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *connectionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",SERVER_URL, RESOURCE_URL_USER_SIGNUP];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:connectionString];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:jsonData];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"response object: %@", (NSDictionary *)responseObject);

    [delegate userSignUpCompletedWithResponse:responseObject];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    [delegate userSignUpFailedWithError:error];
    NSString *errorBodyMessage = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion"];
    NSLog(@"error message: %@", errorBodyMessage);

}];

[operation start];
```

Here, everything is working as expected when http response is 200. I have a REST API on server side which is written in ROR. For the user sign up, if all fields have valid values then it sends 200 status, but if data are invalid, such as *email already taken*; In this case server sends 422 status with error message in JSON. I need to trace error message and show it to mobile user but I am unable to get the message object in error block. I have logged entire error but did not find the object returned form the server. How can I get the JSON object while there is non 2xx http response using AFNetworking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access the `responseObject` property of the `operation` passed into the failure block.

`failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", operation.responseObject);
}];`

Comment: hi, mattt, I got this error while adding the log: 
Property 'responseJSON' not found on object of type 'AFHTTPRequestOperation *'

Comment: That was a typo. It's `responseObject`.

Comment: however it worked while I changed it to NSLog(@"JSON: %@", operation.responseObject);

Comment: @matt After upgrading to AFNetworking 2.0 and using `AFHTTPSessionManager` instead of `AFHTTPRequestOperation` is it still possible to grab out the response object for error response codes (400, 422, etc)?